# How do I generate cross sections of a 3D graphic?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, animation

I would like to approximate the volume of a bottle by summing up the volume of the individual disks. I have obtained code references from a demonstration. But how do I generate the cross sections? The lines do not seem to work.

This was what I wrote in the notebook:

```
For[m = 1, m < n, m++,
 Show[{region, partitionall,
   Table[{xsections[[k]], rightends[[k]], leftends[[k]]}, {k, 1, m}]}, 
   ImageSize -> 300, ViewPoint -> {1, -3, 0},
  DisplayFunction -> $DisplayFunction, PlotRange -> plotrange3d, 
  Boxed -> False]]
```

where

```
xsections := 
 Table[ParametricPlot3D[{u, radii[xgrid[i - 1]]*Cos[t], 
    radii[xgrid[i - 1]]*Sin[t] + centers[xgrid[i - 1]][[2]], 
    EdgeForm[]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, xgrid[i - 1], xgrid[i]}, 
   BaseStyle -> CMYKColor[0, 1, 0], PlotPoints -> {20, 20},
   Boxed -> False, DisplayFunction -> Identity, ImageSize -> 350], {i,
    2, n}]

partition[i_] := 
 Show[Graphics3D[{Thickness[.007],
    Line[{{xgrid[i], 0, bottom[xgrid[i]]}, {xgrid[i], 0, 
       top[xgrid[i]]}}]}], ImageSize -> 300, 
  DisplayFunction -> Identity]

rightends = 
 Table[ParametricPlot3D[{xgrid[i], u*radii[xgrid[i - 1]]*Cos[t],
    u*radii[xgrid[i - 1]]*Sin[t] + centers[xgrid[i - 1]][2],
    EdgeForm[]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 1},
   BaseStyle -> CMYKColor[0, 1, 0], PlotPoints -> {20, 20},
   DisplayFunction -> Identity, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 350], {i,
    2, n}] 

leftends = 
 Table[ParametricPlot3D[{xgrid[i], u*radii[xgrid[i]]*Cos[t],
    u*radii[xgrid[i]]*Sin[t] + centers[xgrid[i]][2]}, {t, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {u, 0, 1},  BaseStyle -> CMYKColor[0, 1, 0], 
   PlotPoints -> {20, 20}, DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
   Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 350], {i, 1, n}]
```

[image: something like this]

Answer (score 9):

Some profile definitions I made up, and an image of the profile.

```
radii = Interpolation[
  {{{0.}, 2.}, {{0.4}, 3.}, {{0.7}, 1.}, {{0.85}, 0.75, 0.}, {{1.}, 0.75, 0.}}];
centers = Interpolation[
  {{{0.}, 0.}, {{0.2}, 0.}, {{0.5}, 1.}, {{0.7}, 0.5}, {{0.85}, 0.2, 0.}, {{1.}, 0.2, 0.}}];

ParametricPlot[{u, t radii[u] + centers[u]}, {u, 0, 1}, {t, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 0.4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solid seems to be a solid of revolution, in which case the approximating cross section is a [`Cylinder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cylinder.html).  The cross section between two parameter values, `u1 <= u <= u2`, can be found with the following function.

```
xsections[u1_, u2_] := Cylinder[{{u1, 0, centers[u1]}, {u2, 0, centers[u1]}}, radii[u1]];
```

To view a cross section, it has to appear inside `Graphics3D`; otherwise it merely represents a region.  To get 15 cross sections, we can partition the interval from `0.` to `1.` into 15 subintervals.  (Change the `15` below to get whatever desired number of cross sections.)

```
Graphics3D[
 xsections @@@ Partition[Range[0., 1., 1./15], 2, 1],
 ViewPoint -> {0.5, -2, 0}, BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If by approximating the volume, one means approximating the measure of the volume (as opposed to the geometric figure itself), then [`RegionMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html) can be applied to each cylinder.  The individual measures can be added up with [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Total.html) or [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Accumulate.html).  `Accumulate` shows the running total.

```
RegionMeasure /@ xsections @@@ Partition[Range[0., 1., 1./15], 2, 1]
Accumulate[%]
(*
{0.837758, 2.18214, 3.1149, 3.39966, 3.14027, 2.56186, 1.88496,
 1.18906, 0.727851, 0.436979, 0.264345, 0.15834, 0.12172, 0.11781, 0.11781}

{0.837758, 3.0199, 6.1348, 9.53446, 12.6747, 15.2366, 17.1216,
 18.3106, 19.0385, 19.4754, 19.7398, 19.8981, 20.0198, 20.1377, 20.2555}
*)
```